# CustomAuthenticationStateProvider Not Update after login in middlware

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, serilog

i use AuthenticationStateProvider for authenticate user in my web app (asp .net core)
all thinks work great and my page perfectly use roles for authorize users ...
but now i want use serilog to log with user login and so on ...

i create middleware and inject AuthenticationStateProvider in it and want to use for Get user to login ...
but always user is null ... why ???

this is my code :

```
public class MiddlewareLogger
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public MiddlewareLogger(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context,AuthenticationStateProvider AS)
        {
            var test = await AS.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            CustomAuthenticationProvider CA = (CustomAuthenticationProvider)AS;
            using (Serilog.Context.LogContext.PushProperty("IP", context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()))
            using (Serilog.Context.LogContext.PushProperty("UserAgent", context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString()))
            using (Serilog.Context.LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", CA?.DIMAuthUser?.UserName))
            using (Serilog.Context.LogContext.PushProperty("UserNameTitle", CA?.DIMAuthUser?.Title))
            {
                await _next(context);
            }

        }


    }
```

and this is log result in seq server :
[image]

as You can see IP and userAgent work great but username and usernameTitle is empty ...

[image]

i use DIMAuthUser Many Time in my whole app page and component and all things work ...
but in middleware always Null ...
why ???

Comment: Are you using Blazor Server or WebAssembly?

Comment: Anyway, this is not how it is supposed to work. AuthenticationStateProvider should be used only within Blazor, not it the rest of ASP.NET Core pipeline.
Also, AuthenticationStateProvider should not be used for login. It should be used only to report the AuthenticationState to Blazor App.

Comment: @Liero Blazor Server ... but i used it for login and access to pages and access part of my page and every things is working .... i used it for hide part of my page or some things else for each user

Comment: I highly recommend you to do login outside of blazor app. You can have `Login.cshtml`, and cookie authentication middleware that redirects all unauthenticated request to login.cshtml. That way you don't need any custom AuthenticationStateProvider. 
Outside of Blazor, you can use HttpContext.User, in Blazor AuthenticationStateProvider to get current authentication state. This is how authentication works in ASP.NET Core, Blazor or not.